# Passing data to added Fragment - IlligalStateException: Fragment already active

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments which is active and showing side by side on a tablet. I need to pass some data from fragmentA to fragmentB when user selects an item from a listview in fragmentA. My problem occurs when trying to get the data from the activity to fragmentB. I'm getting the error: IlligalStateException: Fragment already active.

I pass the data from activity like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onTrackSelected(String trackId) {

        topBarFragment topBarFragment = (topBarFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.topBar_fragment);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("trackId", trackId);
        //set Fragmentclass Arguments
        topBarFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        topBarFragment.onTrackSelected();

    }
```

And then receive in fragmentB like this:

```
public void onTrackSelected() {

        String trackId = getArguments().getString("trackId");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), trackId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }   
}
```

Logcat:

```
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already active
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setArguments(Fragment.java:500)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at com.harteg.fragmentstest.ItemListActivity.onTrackSelected(ItemListActivity.java:88)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at com.harteg.fragmentstest.TracksFragment.onListItemClick(TracksFragment.java:136)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-25 02:58:22.190: E/AndroidRuntime(29593):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't change the arguments you passed to the fragment after it has been created. What you should do is just pass the data in your method call, like this:

```
topBarFragment.onTrackSelected(trackId);
```

And use it on your fragment:

```
public void onTrackSelected(int trackId) {
  Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(trackId),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

For more information have a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) on how to handle communication between fragments.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy.